# width of bootstrap selecpicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I called the bootstrap select picker in angularjs using the following code

```
element.selectpicker(options)
```

Now I want to find the width of the generated select picker and I want to apply inline style to the span inside the select picker to fix some UI issue.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

use [nya-bootstrap-select](http://nya.io/nya-bootstrap-select/#!/)

selectpicker got [deprecated](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select)